# Entire state object in React setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, setstate

I have a huge state and I am doing some updates. Does the second update does more work because it is updating entire state? Or it's all the same backstage?

```
this.setState({
count: 5
})
```

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
return {
    ...prevState,
    count : 5
}
})
```

Comment: How do plan to deal with cases where you want to *remove* properties?  Spread will always include, you can't limit what gets spread in.

Comment: When you're just setting a number like this, use the first because it's obviously less verbose. But if you're dealing with complex structures, the second version is sometimes needed. So use whatever makes sense for the use case. The example is too contrived.

Comment: I updated my question, but what @ggorlen is saying is they are different in terms of being verbose?

Comment: Clearly, yes. Is this the exact state update you're really doing, setting a single key to 5, or is there more to it than that? If all you're doing is setting a field to 5, then use the first--there's no sense in copying the entire state object and allocating a function--it's slower, more typing, harder to read....